# View change with orientation change and preventing activity restart are not working together

Tags: android

I used following code to prevent activity from starting again when phone is rotated..

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

I used following format to get different views for horizontal and vertical displays...

For portrait mode xml in `res/layout-port`, and For landscape xml in `res/layout-land`

The problem is these codes dont work together.....

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

instead of

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

then it will work.

Comment: Sorry it is not working, view does not change when i rotate my phone..only it prevents activity from restarting

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
Create two views with the same name. Move one in res/layout and different in res/layout-land and add this code in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

            ..
}
```

"main" layout is gotten from res/layout-land when phone is land oriented and other "main" is gotten from res/layout when portrait oriented.